# Syntax for memoir's \medievalpage command

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm trying to use the `memoir` class `\medievalpage` command and cannot get it to work. Here is my effort:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\medievalpage
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Your example seems to do what it is supposed to do. What exactly do you mean with "cannot get it to work"?

Comment: I get a single page with a block text area, rather than two columns of text.

Comment: `\medievaltext` only sets the page margins, but doesn't switch to `twocolumn` mode. Try `\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}`.

Comment: Ah, OK. Medieval texts always seemed to be in two columns, I thought it automatically provided that functionality.

Answer (score 6):

The `\medievalpage`, sets the page geometry to comply with [classic page proportions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55502/modern-book-design-margins-and-typed-area).
To get it to two column use:

```
  \documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{memoir}
  \medievalpage
  \checkandfixthelayout
```

This should give a page similar to the image below:

[image]

Comment: How do you put all those lines and frames? Is there a package for that?

Comment: @HarishKumar I am busy writing it:)

Comment: That sounds exciting. When can we expect to get it? Soon?

Comment: @HarishKumar Possibly this weekend I will put it up at Git.

Comment: I am eagerly waiting to use it. Pl. notify it.

Answer (score 4):

`\medievalpage` only sets the page margins, but doesn't switch to `twocolumn` mode -- for the latter, you have to add the `twocolumn` class option. Additionally, I suggest to enlarge the space between columns (LaTeX's default value of 10pt is too small IMO) and to load the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package -- its protrusion and font expansion features result in better line breaks for small columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{memoir}

\medievalpage
\checkandfixthelayout

\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```