# Grids for A4 paper (golden ratio)

Tags: grid-typesetting

I'm about to construct the most important document of my life - my Ph.D. thesis. A while back I came across this for web design:

[Grids are Good](http://www.subtraction.com/pics/0703/grids_are_good.pdf)

Is there anything similar for typesetting A4 papers? Preferably that adheres to the golden ratio. I want my thesis to be as amazing as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Are you looking for a presentation that tells you how to structure an A4 page for the correct placement of images? Or do you want a LaTeX template that places images like that?

Comment: I'm looking for information on how to structure a golden ratio grid across A4 paper. It does not have to be LaTeX specific.

Comment: The `layaureo` package sets the page parameters based on the golden ratio. Unfortunately, it's documented only in Italian, but `\usepackage[binding=4mm]{layaureo}` should be all you need (the `binding` option is not required, of course)

Comment: Use ConTeXt. Seriously.

Comment: The `memoir` manual has some samples of textblock constructions. **But...** I would recommend you not to use A4 as the final size.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Thanks for the "Grids are Good" link.

Comment: @Jellby -- It seems fairly likely that the papersize will be determined by the institution.  My university had a fair amount to say about the layout of the (8.5" x 11") page, and none of it was particularly concerned with what might qualify as good typographical practice.

Comment: This [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55502/8528) might be of interest to you.