# How to typeset a smaller size book with trim marks from letter paper stock?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, memoir, book-design, document-configuration

How could I use the `memoir` package (or anything else, that's just what came to mind) to output a letter paper size document, but typeset with a different page width (9" by 7" in my case) with a trim mark showing where the letter paper should be cut?

I got this far with memoir:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\settypeblocksize{6.5in}{*}{.75}

\trimFrame  
\settrimmedsize{9in}{7in}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

> [image]

This shows the trim marks where I need them, but the typesetting is clearly still based on the 8.5" by 11" letter page. Is there any way to make it typeset on the 7" by 9" page?

Comment: @jon That's the question; I know how to set the page size (if that is all I need I just use Geometry) but I want to be able to print from my home printer and cut it to size based on the marks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to the other answer except that I do not explicitly set the ratio of the left to right margins, but I do explicitly set the stock size. The `\checkandfixthelayout` is key here. Once you add that, you find your initial settings were impossible (it stops with an error telling you this). You can then figure out that you need to alter the spine and fore-edge values using `\setlrmargins`. If applicable, you should also set the top and bottom margin, space for marginal notes etc. before `\checkandfixthelayout`. `memoir` needs to know this stuff in order to calculate things correctly. See page 22 of `\memoir`'s manual for details.

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
\trimFrame
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{7in}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{6.5in}{*}{.75}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
%\setulmargins{}{}{}
%\setheadfoot{}{}
%\setheaderspaces{}{}{}
%\setmarginnotes{}{}{}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll +1 for your extras.  Aside (for @Ryan) the ratio I choose was not random, though it was supposed to be 0.5(!). There's a [good question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55502/8528) that explores margin ratios.

Comment: @jon I already (+1) yours so I can't do it again. `.5` makes more sense.... I just really left it `*` because I didn't know what was wanted in this case. I tried to do this with `zwpagelayout` but I can't get anything sensible.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I think leaving it open is good. I think Yiannis Lazarides' point about the spine-edge ratio makes sense, but it is surely not suitable for all occasions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and @jon thanks for the point about margins, I hadn't gotten that far yet and that value was more or less random. I'm hoping to [work with margins a lot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231728/is-it-possible-to-typeset-with-angled-margins) as I figure out more about how to do all this.

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you want.

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\trimFrame
\settrimmedsize{9in}{7in}{*}% heigh | width | ratio
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{6.5in}{*}{.75}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{0.5}% spine | (fore)edge | ratio
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Note that you need to set `\setlrmargins` in order to avoid `memoir` complaining about your spines and edges being too large. This error only shows up if you forget the all-important `\checkandfixthelayout` (which takes optional arguments: `fixed`, `classic` [= default], `lines`, and `nearest`).