# Is it possible to typeset with angled margins?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, memoir, book-design

I'm typesetting a book using `memoir` in `XeLaTeX`, but on some pages, as an accent, I would like to make an angled margin, something like this:

> [image]

Even if I have to define the page limit separately for each line or something, is this possible with `XeLaTeX` and `Memoir`?

I'm sorry, I would include a MWE but I really don't know where to start.

Comment: About an MWE: why not just this? `\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}` (With appropriate linebreaks inserted.)

Comment: Per-paragraph, see [How to layout irregular paragraph shape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32226/5764). Also see [Very specific paragraph shape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32997/5764) and [Text wrap with shapepar (insert image between text)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34546/5764) for wrapping in arbitrary shapes...

Comment: @PaulGessler I'll update with a MWE next time I have an Internet connection for my computer

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason for the varying paragraph indent in the requested output?

Comment: Doesn't this go against all `memoir` holds dear?

Comment: @cfr for my next question, I'll ask how to implement WordArt in TikZ. Actually though, I think the effect will work well, used sparingly of course, to draw design elements from the cover onto key pages of the book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're patient enough:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainlanguage{latin}
\nonzeroparskip

\begin{document}

\parshape
  12 
  6cm \dimexpr\textwidth-6cm\relax
  5.75cm \dimexpr\textwidth-5.75cm\relax
  5.5cm \dimexpr\textwidth-5.5cm\relax
  5.25cm \dimexpr\textwidth-5.25cm\relax
  5cm \dimexpr\textwidth-5cm\relax
  4.75cm \dimexpr\textwidth-4.75cm\relax
  4.5cm \dimexpr\textwidth-4.5cm\relax
  4.25cm \dimexpr\textwidth-4.25cm\relax
  4cm \dimexpr\textwidth-4cm\relax
  3.75cm \dimexpr\textwidth-3.75cm\relax
  3.5cm \dimexpr\textwidth-3.5cm\relax
  3.25cm \dimexpr\textwidth-3.25cm\relax
\lipsum[2]
\parshape
  8 
  3cm \dimexpr\textwidth-3cm\relax
  2.75cm \dimexpr\textwidth-2.75cm\relax
  2.5cm \dimexpr\textwidth-2.5cm\relax
  2.25cm \dimexpr\textwidth-2.25cm\relax
  2cm \dimexpr\textwidth-2cm\relax
  1.75cm \dimexpr\textwidth-1.75cm\relax
  1.5cm \dimexpr\textwidth-1.5cm\relax
  1.25cm \dimexpr\textwidth-1.25cm\relax
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: well, you could re-define `\par` so that it's actually `\\\hspace*{\parindent}`, and then you could do that page-by-page. Note also that the line-breaking algorithm slows down with this.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to my question, it's in response to Gonzalo Medina when he says "if you're patient enough"

I do not have the patience, but I do have python.

```python
from __future__ import division

margin = -.25
step = .07

def paragraph(lines,margin,step,name):
    print "\\newcommand{\paragraph%s}{" %(name)
    print " \parshape"
    print " ",lines
    for lines in range(0,lines):
        print " %sin\dimexpr\\textwidth-%sin\\relax" %(margin, margin)
        margin = margin+step
    print "}"
    print ""
    return margin + (.75*step)

margin = paragraph(1,margin,step,"click")
margin = paragraph(5,margin,step,"one")
margin = paragraph(7,margin,step,"two")
margin = paragraph(4,margin,step,"three")
margin = paragraph(3,margin,step,"four")
margin = paragraph(3,margin,step,"five")
```

This script calculates a straight angled margin, starting with the "`margin`" and then stepping each line in by "`step`."

This script generates the parshape code, as commands, to automatically calculate across paragraphs and stuff. It outputs:

```
\newcommand{\paragraphclick}{
    \parshape
    1
    -0.25in\dimexpr\textwidth--0.25in\relax
}

\newcommand{\paragraphone}{
    \parshape
    5
    -0.1275in\dimexpr\textwidth--0.1275in\relax
    -0.0575in\dimexpr\textwidth--0.0575in\relax
    0.0125in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.0125in\relax
    0.0825in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.0825in\relax
    0.1525in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.1525in\relax
}

\newcommand{\paragraphtwo}{
    \parshape
    7
    0.275in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.275in\relax
    0.345in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.345in\relax
    0.415in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.415in\relax
    0.485in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.485in\relax
    0.555in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.555in\relax
    0.625in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.625in\relax
    0.695in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.695in\relax
}

\newcommand{\paragraphthree}{
    \parshape
    4
    0.8175in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.8175in\relax
    0.8875in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.8875in\relax
    0.9575in\dimexpr\textwidth-0.9575in\relax
    1.0275in\dimexpr\textwidth-1.0275in\relax
}

\newcommand{\paragraphfour}{
    \parshape
    3
    1.15in\dimexpr\textwidth-1.15in\relax
    1.22in\dimexpr\textwidth-1.22in\relax
    1.29in\dimexpr\textwidth-1.29in\relax
}

\newcommand{\paragraphfive}{
    \parshape
    3
    1.4125in\dimexpr\textwidth-1.4125in\relax
    1.4825in\dimexpr\textwidth-1.4825in\relax
    1.5525in\dimexpr\textwidth-1.5525in\relax
}
```

And then you can label each paragraph with the corresponding command: `\paragraphone` `\paragraphtwo` `\paragraphthree` or whatever you set the `python` script to name them.

Wish I'd written this in `Lua` for use with `LuaLaTeX`, but oh well.

It would probably only take about an hour for me to make this into a basic `LuaLaTeX` package...