# Set what parameters how with memoir for specified paperhight and paperwidth on specified stocksize?

Tags: margins, memoir

In trying to specify page dimensions, the more I read memman.pdf, the more confused I get!  Here's what I want:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{9.1in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{6.3in}
\settypeblocksize{44pc}{28pc}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1-10]

\end{document}
```

Command `\checkandfixthelayout` gives error: \spinemargin (109.26999pt) and/or \textwidth (336.0pt) and/or \foremargin (164.02501pt) are too large for specified \paperwidth (455.3012pt) by 153.99379pt.

Exactly what other parameters do I need to set, and at what values, so as to accommodate the specified letterpaper stock (from the `\setstocksize` command or, alternatively, a `letterpaper` option to `documentclass`), the specified after-trimming physical size (from `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`), and the specified typeblock size?

**Second try**

Following the method shown in [How to typeset a smaller size book with trim marks from letter paper stock?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231596/how-to-typeset-a-smaller-size-book-with-trim-marks-from-letter-paper-stock), I tried:

```
\documentclass[showtrims]{memoir}
%\trimFrame
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{56.25pc}{38pc}{*}
\settrims{0in}{0in}
\settypeblocksize{44pc}{28pc}{*}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Now I get a different error: \fontskip (25.29494pt) is too large for \lowermargin (12.66252pt) by 12.63242pt.

Comment: You need to also say something about the margin sizes. Try including `\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}` and `\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}` to tell memoir to compute them using the default formula.

Comment: Aha, `\setulmargins` was indeed the missing ingredient after my 2nd try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

You can use `\settrimmedsize{⟨height⟩}{⟨width⟩}{⟨ratio⟩}` to avoid defining `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` (they get calculated based on `\trimmedsize`) and then you just need to calculate the margins as Willie Wong said:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{9.1in}{6.3in}{*}
\settypeblocksize{44pc}{28pc}{*}

% As Willie Wong said:
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{*}

\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum{1-10]

\end{document}
```