# Are margins correct for two-sided memoir?

Tags: margins, memoir, double-sided

The default twoside memoir document style makes the right margin really large on recto (odd) pages and the left margin really large on verso (even) pages.

This seems counter-intuitive to me.  It seems to me that you want the large margin against the spine of the book, to compensate for the part of the margin lost to the binding process.

So is the default style really what one wants for publishing, or do I need to customize the margins to be the opposite of what they are by default?

Comment: Bear in mind that the size of a physical printed page (A4 or US Letter Paper) is not normally the size of a printed book page, which tends to be smaller. But, please see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55502/8528) for more discussion.

Comment: This is a long tradition. Have a look at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/memdesign?lang=en, where the memoir author explains a some typographic history. There are also many post on this site that explains this.

Comment: this is a faq and a duplicate here. The outer margins are typically twice as wide as the inner margins, so that (a) the two inner margins together make similar space and (b) you have somewhere to put your hands to hold the book.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Sorry that this is a duplicate question.  I did search but didn't find it on my own.