# Is there a package that draws a diagonal line over the page - not using TikZ

Tags: packages, margins, draw

For finding right margins, it might be interesting to display on each page the diagonal of the page (as well as the diagonal of the double page), see the pictures in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55502/28751), where this picture

[image: Canonical page construction]

probably gets best the intended result (just the diagonals).

Of course, one could do it with TikZ, but due to the externalization process I would prefer to get it without TikZ. Best would be a result that puts this over every page, similar like the `showframe` commands.

Comment: The problem is that you need some picture command to draw the line. Not so easy to get an accurate angle without tikz. You could try a rotatebox + eso-pic.

Comment: What's wrong with tikz?

Comment: Not much, I love to use it. However, I was not aware of the trick shown in the [answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369301/28751).

Answer (score 17):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
\makeatletter

\dimen4=.996264\paperheight
\dimen6=.996264\paperwidth

\pdfliteral page{%
q
n
0  0 m
\strip@pt\dimen6 \space \strip@pt\dimen4 \space l
s
Q}
\begin{document}
zzzz
\end{document}
```

Comment: to put it on every page just define `\@oddhead` to have that `\pdfliteral` (or `\@evenhead` as well for two sided documents)

Comment: Or use everypage.  Wow!  I have a PDF manual (1213 pages) but it never showed how to do anything like that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm sure the pdf manual has an example of drawing a line somewhere (it did last time I looked, I think:-)

Comment: Ouch, that's pretty low level....

Comment: @JPi I think you meant to say "nice, that's impressively efficient" ?

Comment: Absolutely, of course.

Comment: Great impressively efficient answer. However, could you please comment the code a bit more? For me not being a TeX-wizard it is quite difficult to follow.

Comment: @jjdb It's just PDF not tex, `q`= save state `n` = new path, `0 0 m` = move to origin `xx yy l` = line to xx yy, `s` = stroke (draw) the path, `Q` = restore state. .996264 is 72/72.27 = conversion from tex to pdf points

Comment: Unfortunately it is incompatible with the `lscape` package: `\begin{landscape}zzzz\end{landscape}`.

Comment: @AlexG not really incompatible just "unaware":  it assumes that the height is `\paperheight` and the width is `\paperwidth` if in some context you have swapped those round you need to swap them here as well.  That is sort of inevitable in a package-free core primitives solution as here: you need to test for those things explicitly.

Comment: Actually, the outbox of a landscape page (without header and footer) is rotated for shipout, `\textwidth` and `\textheight` were swapped previously, but `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` remain untouched.

Comment: @AlexG I know what lscape does (I wrote it:-) but I just meant that you need to adjust the coordinates to whatever you need, if you are just poking literal pdf drawing operators into the output you can't expect it to automatically adjust to some latex package being loaded.

Answer (score 11):

This not using tikz ;-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
\AtPageLowerLeft{%
 \begin{pgfpicture}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0mm}{\paperheight}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{0mm}}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
 \end{pgfpicture}}}%
blub\newpage blub
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's funny...

Comment: A great answer, thank you too. the problem was mainly with the `externalize`, which could also be solved as shown in the other answer. However, I tried to implement your solution, but wandered into difficulties for the upper semi-diagonals. I put that as a new [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/369435/28751).

Answer (score 10):

You could also use package `pict2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \Line(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},0)(0,\LenToUnit{\paperheight})%
  }%
}
Text\newpage Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\newcommand*\snum{10}% number of segments
\KOMAoptions{DIV=\snum}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{segment}
\newlength\circletextwidth
\setlength\circletextwidth{\paperwidth*\ratio{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
      \setcounter{segment}{1}
      \whiledo{\value{segment}<\snum}{%
        \Line
          (\LenToUnit{\value{segment}\paperwidth/\snum},0)%
          (\LenToUnit{\value{segment}\paperwidth/\snum},\LenToUnit{\paperheight})%
        \Line
          (0,\LenToUnit{\value{segment}\paperheight/\snum})%
          (\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\value{segment}\paperheight/\snum})%
        \stepcounter{segment}%
      }%
      \linethickness{2pt}%
      \moveto(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth/\snum},\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/\snum})%
        \lineto(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth-2\paperwidth/\snum},\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/\snum})%
        \lineto(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth-2\paperwidth/\snum},\LenToUnit{\paperheight-\paperheight/\snum})%
        \lineto(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth/\snum},\LenToUnit{\paperheight-\paperheight/\snum})%
        \closepath
        \textcolor{red}{\strokepath}%
      \textcolor{blue}{%
        \Line(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},0)(0,\LenToUnit{\paperheight})%
        \Line(0,\LenToUnit{.5\paperheight})(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\paperheight})%
      }
    \else
      \linethickness{2pt}%
      \moveto(\LenToUnit{2\paperwidth/3-2\circletextwidth/3},\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/3-2\paperwidth/3})%
        \lineto(\LenToUnit{2\paperwidth/3+\circletextwidth/3},\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/3-2\paperwidth/3})%
        \lineto(\LenToUnit{2\paperwidth/3+\circletextwidth/3},\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/3+\paperwidth/3})%
        \lineto(\LenToUnit{2\paperwidth/3-2\circletextwidth/3},\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/3+\paperwidth/3})%
        \closepath
        \textcolor{red}{\strokepath}%
        \moveto(\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{5\paperheight/\snum})%
        \circlearc[1]{\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth}}{\LenToUnit{2\paperheight/3-\paperwidth/6}}
          {\LenToUnit{.5\paperwidth}}{0}{360}%
        \textcolor{green}{\strokepath}%
      \textcolor{blue}{%
          \Line(0,0)(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{\paperheight})%
          \Line(0,0)(\LenToUnit{\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{.5\paperheight})%
      }%
    \fi
  }%
}
\Blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

Changing `\snum` to `8`

```
\newcommand*\snum{8}
```

results in

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Since you already have your answer and mentioned as the reason for your preference not to use `TikZ` potential problems with the `external` library, I thought I'd add a solution showing that this can be worked around, for others who (like me) at some point have gotten tripped up by this. Maybe you already know this anyway but still prefer not to use `TikZ`, in which case apologies for bothering you. But just in case not:

You can disable and enable externalization for specific sections of your document or single pictures via:

- `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` (p.613 in `pgfman.pdf`)
- `\tikzset{external/export next=false}` (or `true`, if you so desire). (p.612 in `pgfman.pdf`). I use this heavily to decorate `chapter` and `part` pages and a few other things in a class I'm writing, while still having `external` enabled by default, and it has served me quite well.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize %Enable
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

% This picture will be externalized
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Disable externalization from here on forward
\tikzexternaldisable

% These two pictures will not be externalized
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[red] (current page.north east) -- (current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[cyan] (current page.east) -- (current page.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Enable externalization from here on forward
\tikzexternalenable

% This picture will be externalized
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Disable Externalize for the next picture only
\tikzset{external/export next=false}%
% This picture will not be externalized
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[blue] (current page.south east) -- (current page.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

% This picture will be externalized. Note that we did not
% have to re-enable externalization explicitly.
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[magenta] (5,0) rectangle (11,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: result]