# Modern layout: Can LaTeX calculate best fit over 2 or 3 columns?

Tags: pdftex

**modern**

I am looking for example (with *.tex) of a modern (not like a diploma work) book/brochure layout with two or three columns and a lot of pictures which take place over one or also two colums.

So how can I create *exactly (because of Q/A-site)* this design:

[image: example]

[example](https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F5e%2Fae%2F53%2F5eae53643df2f4d8e378fdf92d188e51.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.de%2Fpin%2F477522366712123290%2F&docid=_I9JspT-AI0gTM&tbnid=yX8h64TzRJ8p-M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjF_JSso5fbAhVPZlAKHaZ6DH4QMwhWKBUwFQ..i&w=600&h=400&itg=1&bih=807&biw=1068&q=modern%20brochure%20design&ved=0ahUKEwjF_JSso5fbAhVPZlAKHaZ6DH4QMwhWKBUwFQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)

**fit best**

The text and the pictures should always fit best together. Can LaTeX calculate this over 2 odr 3 columns? So picture of the text is not of the previous of next side.

[image: example]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Related [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55502/124842). This is a Q/A site and not a forum.

Comment: No idea? No one?