# Encircling Margin Notes in Column Format?

Tags: margins, two-column, marginpar, marginnote

I recently saw this old manuscript with the text arranged in a very curious way, and I wanted to know if it could be replicated. The text is from Accursius' *Magna Glossa*, a commentary on Emperor Justinian's Pandects.

It consists of two columns of text––Justinian's Laws––at the center of the page, easily recreated with `twocolumn`.

What is special is that *then* the explanation/commentary of these laws consists of **two columns** in the **margins** that **wrap around** the central main text of the laws, above, below, and on the sides (see picture attached for clarity).

Margin notes are no problem, and can be added either with the `\marginnote` package or through the default `\marginpar` command. I am, however, completely clueless as to how to make margin notes configured into two continuous columns that wrap around the main text.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image: Main center text (in two columns) surrounded by margin commentary (also in two columns, the right continuing the text written on the left).]

Comment: have a  look at this post ```https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56190/197451

Comment: Interesting! Unfortunately, it does not have the answer I am looking for, but it does have information that I have found pretty useful. In the end, I think I will try to create a standard two-column text and insert a separate floating figure of text in the middle.